# Why is my background image stretched out in libGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

This is my first try in libGDX and I've not seen an issue like this before, googling didn't help either. What I'm trying to to display a background, Later on I'll make this move, but for me it was a great start to actually display the image. It displays, but it's streched out (See picture below)

[image]

And my code is:

```
private BombArrangement game;
private OrthographicCamera gameCamera;
private Viewport gamePort;
private Texture backGroundTexture;

public PlayScreen(BombArrangement game) {
    this.game = game;
    gameCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
    gamePort = new FitViewport(BombArrangement.V_WIDTH, BombArrangement.V_HEIGHT, gameCamera);

    backGroundTexture = new Texture("startbackground.png");
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(new TextureRegion(backGroundTexture, 0, 0, BombArrangement.V_WIDTH, BombArrangement.V_HEIGHT), 0, 0);
    game.batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    gamePort.update(width, height);
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
}
```

I tried several things like textureregions, sprites and more but all of them give this result.

Comment: What do you mean by stretched out? What is it supposed to look like? Smaller? Or filling the whole screen?

Comment: I want my picture to fill the screen, this is the original picture https://i.imgur.com/RUaxa5g.jpg. It needs to fill the height and 1920 pixels from the width

Comment: What is `BombArrangement.V_WIDTH` and `BombArrangement.V_HEIGHT`

Comment: I don't know nothing about libgdx, maybe a libgdx pro can help, but to me it looks like, you maybe want to try the ExtendViewport. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: I actually use those, V_HEIGHT = 1920 and V_WIDTH = 1080

Comment: So, height is bigger than width, explains the ratio. And FitViewPort explains the black bars.

Comment: Indeed, I'm making an android game but thats the ratio the game will be in. I want to display the first 1080 and 1920 pixels of the picture.

Comment: "It needs to fill the height and 1920 pixels from the width". "V_HEIGHT = 1920", should the height be 1920 or should the width be 1920? Should it be displayed on an android or as in the photo on a PC? If on android, should it be portrait mode or landscape mode?

Whats the height of the window? Isn't the window size limiting how much you see of the image? You wont see more pixels than the window size allows. If you resize it do you see more of it then?

Comment: Portrait mode, I changed my V_WIDTH to 480 and V_HEIGHT to 800. And in my desktop launcher I set the screen to 480 by 800. But I still see a small portion of the picture

Comment: I still dont quite understand what you are trying to accomplish. How would your goal image look like? If you want to display a 3413x1920 image on a 480x800 screen you either have to scale it down and/or crop it. Right now it's cropped but I guess you also want to scale it down to fit the screen vertically but keep the image ratio (i.e. only display a part of its width)?

Comment: Hello, I changed my code and it's now displaying the image almost correctly. I want my screen to fill with the image as far as it can without changing the scale of the image.
new code: https://hastebin.com/mecocigada.java
The result isn't what I want, but it looks better than before. I'm only having issues with the width right now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7131tDe8KDg

Answer (score 1):

not exactly sure what your want to do but i use this to render my background in my main menu:

```
    //Camera
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    //Viewport
    ScreenViewport viewport = new ScreenViewport(camera); 

    //Background
    backgroundImage = new Texture(pathToImage);

    //Stage 
    stage = new Stage();
    stage.setViewport(viewport);
```

(this is located in my constructor and camera, backgroundImage and stage are fields in my class)

in render method
(ConfigData holds data of settings applied to the game; DEFAULT_WIDHT and -HEIGHT are just some values I use to initialize the window when not in fullscreen mode; Replace them with your values used in the DesktopLauncher for

```
config.widht
```

and

```
config.height
```

):

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    //Clear screen
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act();
    stage.getBatch().begin();
    stage.getBatch().draw(backgroundImage, 0, 0, ConfigData.DEFAULT_WIDTH, ConfigData.DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    stage.getBatch().end();

    stage.draw();
}
```

my resize method:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
}
```

hopes this helps somehow someone because i figured out this by myself and it costed some effort (:

Answer (score 0):

*As a response to your last comment:*

You are now scaling down the height correctly but the width remains the same. Try to multiply the width by the same amount you scale the height down, so with some alterations to the code you linked in the comment (not tested):

```
private Texture texture;
private int x1, x2, speed, scaledHeight, scaledWidth;

public StartBackground() {
    texture = new Texture("startbackground.png");

    x1 = 0;
    x2 = texture.getWidth();
    speed = 5;
    float imageRatio = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / texture.getHeight();
    scaledHeight = (int) (texture.getHeight() * imageRatio);
    scaledWidth = (int) (texture.getWidth() * imageRatio);
}

public void updateAndRender(float deltaTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
    x1 -= speed;
    x2 -= speed;

    // If image is off screen and not visible
    if (x1 + texture.getWidth() <= 0) x1 = x2 + texture.getWidth();
    if (x2 + texture.getWidth() <= 0) x2 = x1 + texture.getWidth();

    // Render
    spriteBatch.draw(texture, x1, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
    spriteBatch.draw(texture, x2, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
}
```